# Fatal error with jsoncpp while compiling

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Am new to cpp but as per project requirements i need to consume rest api and parse the response.
Am able to call api & capture the response but not able to parse it using JSONCPP library.

These are the steps i followed to parse json:

1. Used this command to install libjsoncpp in ubuntu
   **sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev**
2. Downloaded json source files and copied json header files into project folder
3. Compiling cpp using this command
   **gcc -o test.out test.cpp -ljson**

it is always giving

```
fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
 #include <json/json.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Didn't find any solution since 2 days. Tried [this](http://dannykim.me/danny/openflow/69256?ckattempt=1) also.
Can any one tell me where i am going wrong...

Comment: What does "Downloaded json source files and copied json header files into project folder" mean exactly?

Comment: I was facing same issue as this on macos. For me converting `#include <json/json.h>` to `#include "json/json.h"` did the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're on Ubuntu I went to their package website and found the file list for the package you installed: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libjsoncpp-dev/filelist

The first few files make the problem clear:

```
/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/autolink.h
/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/config.h
/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/features.h
/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/forwards.h
/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h
```

Since compilers usually look in `/usr/include`, **you need to provide the rest of the path, i.e.:**

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
```

You could also have found this file on your running system after installing the package by running this command:

```
locate json.h
```

Or using the `dpkg` command after installing the package.

And when you link your program, you need to say `-ljsoncpp`, not `-ljson`.

Comment: I'm confused, what does he have to change with the #include statement

Comment: @AviParshan Instead of `#include <json/json.h>`, it's `#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>`.

Comment: Hello,  I am having the same issue on mac. Although I installed the jsoncpp lib and cmake command runs fine, but make command complains about `"jsoncpp/json/json.h" not found` But my IDE shows the the file when I change the include into `json/json.h`and doesn't give any error but make command still says `"json/json.h" not found` have any idea?

Comment: @AkilDemir: Search your disk for `json.h`.  What's the full path to it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the full path to it `/usr/local/include/json/json.h`.

Comment: @AkilDemir: Then on your system you need to say `#include <json/json.h>` and you may also need to compile with `-I/usr/local/include` if that's not working by default.

Comment: @JohnZwinck As I have stated above, even when I do `<json/json.h>` Vscode sees the the file there but make command still fails. I have another libraries over there and they just work fine. I have no idea what is goin on. Only thing is Vscode still says `include erros detected consider updating your include path`and nothing more.

Comment: Right, you need to add `/usr/local/include` to your include path.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have tried auto costruct a new cmake environment with Vscode and I got an error with cmake command this time which is ```CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/jsoncpp/jsoncppConfig.cmake:75 (message):
[cmake]   The imported target "jsoncpp_lib" references the file
[cmake]      "/usr/local/lib/libjsoncpp.a"
[cmake]   but this file does not exist.  ``` I had installed the jsoncpp via Homebrew.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have solved the problem by moving the project to Xcode. Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: expected/usual consumption-side include prefix style syntax appears to be
#include <json/json.h>
, not
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
, according to e.g.
[jsoncpp official source](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/github/jsoncpp/dist/doxygen/jsoncpp-api-html-0.6.0-dev/json__writer_8cpp_source.html).
IOW, it is the job of the build system environment to be specifying the default include path (e.g.: /usr/local/include/jsoncpp[<json/json.h>), and doing so by using the correct prefix (examples: /usr , /usr/local , /opt, ...), i.e. the one where the required installation can be found.

Answer (score 5):

another solution:

```js
sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev 
sudo ln -s /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/ /usr/include/json
```