# Docker build is throwing error "fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory FROM ubuntu:14.04"

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile

The application is working for VM but failing when we are deploying using docker file.We have installed json cpp package, still it throws the error mentioned in the title.

Tried :In docker file:

```
RUN apt-get -y install libcairomm-1.0* libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libjsoncpp-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

where libjsoncpp would have sorted the problem, but it is throwing error No such file or directory.

Comment: I think this is most suitable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861355/fatal-error-with-jsoncpp-while-compiling

Comment: This is an incomplete question. It is true [`libjsoncpp-dev` installs `/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libjsoncpp-dev/filelist), but do you compile with `-I/usr/include/jsoncpp`? Please provide a [mcve] or at least a complete and minimal buildchain.