# Fatal error with jsoncpp while compiling for Darwin

Tags: c++, macos, jsoncpp

I am facing the exact same error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861355/fatal-error-with-jsoncpp-while-compiling) but for mac os

Error message looks like this:

```
myfile.cpp:12:10: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
```

initially I was trying to run it like this:

`g++-11 myfile.cpp -o myfile -ljsoncpp`

then I changed it to this:

`g++-11 -L/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp myfile.cpp -o myfile -ljsoncpp`

and then to this:

`g++-11 -I/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp/include -L/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp myfile.cpp -o myfile -ljsoncpp`

and then to this:

`g++-11  -I./json -L/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp myfile.cpp -o myfile -ljsoncpp`

and then to this:

`g++-11 -I/path/to/current/dir/json -L/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp pingpong.cpp -o pingpong -ljsoncpp`

myfile.cpp was like this intitally:

```
#include <json/json.h>
...
```

then influenced by [this](https://github.com/stardust95/TinyCompiler/issues/2#issuecomment-393066038) post I changed it to this:

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
...
```

but no matter what I do I seem to get the same error

This:

`find /usr -name json.h | grep -f json/`
Doesnt return anything.

PS: The path of `jsoncpp` that I used is what I got from this:

`brew info jsoncpp`

```
==> jsoncpp: stable 1.9.5, HEAD
Library for interacting with JSON
https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/jsoncpp.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: meson ✘, ninja ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 4,398 (30 days), 672 (90 days), 66,483 (365 days)
install-on-request: 2,808 (30 days), 86 (90 days), 3,736 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

`brew --prefix jsoncpp`

```
/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp
```

Comment: Where is the json.h file located relative to `/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp/include`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja which file are you asking? `myfile.cpp`? `myfile.cpp` is in my current folder.

Comment: Where is `json.h` located?

Comment: Here is the current directory structure:

>.
>├── json
>│   ├── json-forwards.h
>│   └── json.h
>└── myfile.cpp
>

Comment: What is the contents of `/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles you are right `/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp` is the wrong path . No such path exists. `brew --prefix jsoncpp` probably doesnt give the path of the package

Comment: `-I/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp/include` tells the compiler to add that directory to where it looks for included files. If the file you're trying to include is somewhere under that directory then you need to use the relative path from the specified path to find it. So, figure out where the file is and add a `-I/some/path` that allows the compiler to find it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried  `-I./json ` as well, same error.

Comment: Guys I still haven't found the answer, if you feel its too trivial and worth closing please point to the correct answer before doing so

Comment: It seems you are not familiar with how C++ builds programs and the various steps.  The first step is compilation, and that is where your build is failing, at that step.  The issue is that the compiler does not find your header files you've specified in your source code.  You specify the header by giving the *correct* path of the header files in the command-line.  Since we don't have access to your system, you will have to figure out the exact path.  The `-l` flag plays no role in compiling the source code -- that is used in the link step.

Comment: If the file is in the `json` directory relative to the file including it then `#include "json/json.h"` should find it without any `-I` on the command line. You've shown two examples for how you tried including the file so when you say "I tried -Iwhatever and it didn't work" I have no way of knowing what the `#include` line currently looks like.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie only 3rd party header apart from system headers are in `/path/to/current /directory/json/` rest of the headers should be fine as I have run several c++ code on this system in past using `g++-11 myfile.cpp`. So there is nothing really more you can know by having access to my system than what I already told you.

Comment: Run `find /usr -name json.h | grep -f json/` and show the found paths.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes exactly, original documentation of the project neither recommends any `-L` or `-I` .As I said I couldn't get `g++-11 myfile.cpp -o myfile -ljsoncpp` working, so added all those as debugging effort.

Comment: Did you try exactly what I said and use `#include "json/json.h"`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes converting `#include <json/json.h>` to `#include "json/json.h"` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @273K didn't output anything.

Comment: guys can someone tell me the way to find path of `jsoncpp` . there is nothing called `/usr/local/opt/jsoncpp` ? I cant get what ` brew --prefix jsoncpp` is supposed to output

Comment: `find /usr -name json.h | grep -F json/` did not found, because the files are in `/opt`, you have confused me with `/usr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-I/opt/homebrew/include` is the include directory for `#include <json/json.h>`.

`-L/opt/homebrew/lib` is the library directory for `-ljsoncpp`.

The include and the library paths are valid for the most of homebrew packages.

`/opt/homebrew/opt/jsoncpp` is the install directory.

You could install `brew install pkg-config`. Then the compiler and the linker flags can be retrieved:

```
$ pkg-config jsoncpp --cflags --libs
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/lib -ljsoncpp
```

And the build command:

```
$ g++-11 myfile.cpp -o myfile `pkg-config jsoncpp --cflags --libs`
```

Comment: which macos are you on, I am on osx High Siera(10.13.6). I dont have `/opt/homebrew`
Doing a reinstall I found paths are:
```-I/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/include 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/lib 
```

Comment: and `pkg-config jsoncpp --cflags --libs` says `Package jsoncpp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
`

Answer (score 0):

As @RetiredNinja pointed out converting `#include <json/json.h>` to `#include "json/json.h"` did the trick.